# The Modal body not render the component in html after button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am new to react. I try to use the button onClick to call function for render the component in html.

After execution,  does not appear on the page. Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoR2g.jpg

But when I check the html element (F12), the react-c3js element is contains the  element, and then it suddenly appears in the screen, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a7ya.jpg

But if I don't look at it and wait, the chart will never appear.

This is my .js file

```
// draw the Chart in html
function drawHistoryChart(data) {
    console.log("data: ", data);
    const data2 = {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<C3Chart data={data2} />, document.getElementById('react-c3js'));
}

//
class CarPark extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        parkId: "Not Found Id",
        parkName: "Not Found Name",
        address: "Not Found Address",
        totalSpace: 0,
        surplusSpace: 0,
        payGuide: "Not Found Pay Guide",
    };
    static propTypes = {
        parkId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        parkName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        address: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        totalSpace: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        surplusSpace: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        payGuide: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    // Fetch data and pass data to drawHistoryChart Function
    requestHistoryOfCarPark(parkId, week, time) {
        fetch("/findHistoryByCarPark?place=" + parkId + "&week=" + week + "&time=" + time)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            }).then((jsonData) => {
                drawHistoryChart(jsonData);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('error: ', err);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <button className="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onClick={() => this.requestHistoryOfCarPark(this.props.parkId, getWeek(), getTime())}><i className='fas fa-search' style={style}></i></button>
                    {this.props.parkId}-{this.props.parkName}
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div>地址：{this.props.address}</div>
                    <div>總車位：{this.props.totalSpace}</div>
                    <div>剩餘車位：{this.props.surplusSpace}</div>
                    <div>價錢資訊：{this.props.payGuide}</div>
                </div>
            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="react-c3js"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Very grateful for any help！

Comment: Where is your Modal? In the same js file?

Comment: @ravibagul91, About the Modal, I wrote directly on html and just changed the contents of modal-body by Component

Comment: @Mars You should create a modal component and not use HTML like that in React. I posted an answer. I hope it helps. Basically you want to put more React in your React if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

Your code isn't working because you are not handling the Javascript for the toggling of the Modal correctly. React is a Javascript library, if you are using it take full advantage of it.

You do not need to pass `data-toggle` attributes in your HTML. You don't want to use straight up HTML like that if you are using React. You want to create a `Modal` functional component and use JSX. Convert your `modal` HTML into a React functional component that accepts `isOpen` and has a `onClose` method.

### Solution

There isn't a one size fits all solution to your issue here. You can approach this in a couple ways. You could create a `Modal` component on tap on the shoulders of a library to do the heavy lifting for you. I strongly recommend the latter since you are new. Then play around with building your own component yourself.

Two libraries that are popular with React are `Material UI` or `Reactstrap`.

You can read up on Material UI here: https://material-ui.com/. And Reactstrap here: https://reactstrap.github.io/

These libraries have a ton of Bootstrap goodies that you can play around with in your application.

Here's an example of how you could use `Reactstrap` in you component to get started.

#### Reactstrap: Modals

Add `Reactstrap` to your project. Using npm: `npm i reactstrap react-dom` or using yarn: `yarn add reactstrap react-dom`. I assume you have bootstrap installed as well since you are using the bootstrap classes. You should be good to go to start using `reactstrap` at this point.

**Updating CarPark Component**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

class CarPark extends Component {
   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false) //creating a state variable isOpen whose default value is false
   
  //fetch your data method

   //function for toggling the modal, accepts no params
   //ES6 notation, the arrow function
   const toggleModal = () => {
     setIsOpen(!isOpen); //setting state equivalent to this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen })
   }; 

   //function for opening the modal and calling requestHistoryOfCarPark
   const handleOpenModal = () => {
     const { parkId } = this.props; //destructuring props so you don't have to right this.props.parkId everywhere you can just call parkId
     this.requestHistoryOfCarPark(parkId, getWeek(), getTime());
     setIsOpen(true); //whenever the button is clicked always open the modal
   }; 

   render() {
     const { address, parkId, parkName, payGuide, surplusSpace, totalSpace } = this.props //destructuring props again

     return(
      //this <> empty tag is a Fragment
      <>
       <Card>
        <CardHeader>
          <Button onClick={handleOpenModal}><i className='fas fa-search' style={style}></i></Button>
          { parkId } - { parkName }
        </CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
          <div>{ address } </div>
          <div> { totalSpace } </div>
          <div> { surplusSpace } </div>
          <div> { payGuide } </div>
        </CardBody>
       </Card>
       //Put your modal under the component where you want to access it
       <Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggleModal}>
        <ModalHeader tag='h4'> Modal Heading </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody><div id="react-c3js"></div></ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color='secondary' onClick={toggleModal}>Close</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
       </Modal>
     </> 
    )
}
```

}

**Fragments** I wrapped the `Card` and `Modal` inside of a Fragment you could just as easily use a `<div></div>` but fragments allow you to have sibling components without needing to wrap in an HTML parent i.e. `<div>`. You can read up on Fragments [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment).

### Suggestion

I know getting into a new framework is exciting and you just want to dive right in, but I highly recommend reading through the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) (which can be daunting) and doing some tutorials or reading walkthrough guides.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if any other Reacters see room for improvement in my answer please feel free to edit or post a comment :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I find the solution for this question is my fetch occur some error lead to the graph not appear on the page.